# подскажите почему не работает? Не выделяются иконки

Tags: css3, html5

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #f39c12;

}

.form-control:focus + .form-field__icon{
    color: #f39c12;

}

---

```
                      <div class="contact-form">
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                              placeholder="Mike">
                            <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="icon- 
                             ico6"></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                            placeholder="Email">
                            <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="icon- 
                            mail"></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                             <textarea class="form-control" 
                             placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                             <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="icon- 
                              pen"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Иконки сделаны иконочным шрифтом?

Comment: Иконки шрифтами через Icomoon

Answer (score 0):

Вроде всё работает

```css
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #f39c12;
}
.form-control:focus + .form-field__icon{
  color: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="">
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mike">
    <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <span class="form-field__icon"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: У меня без bootstrap

Comment: Это иконочный шрифт `fontAwesome`. По своей сути он точно такой же как и шрифты, генерируемые сервисом icomoon.

Comment: Причина, по которой может не менятся цвет иконок icomoon - загрузка цветных svg-иконок в генератор шрифта.

Comment: Да,через font Awesome работает! Благодарю